# returning to beginning of loop python blackjack graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a game of blackjack. Unfortunately it can't just be code it has to be shown graphically.
So here's the code I have (it's a doozy):

```
import graphics as gr
import random
win = gr.GraphWin("Blackjack", 700, 700)
win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 61.0, 80.0)

#Game Title
ptitle = gr.Point(30, 77)
title = gr.Text(ptitle, "Black Jack")
title.draw(win)

#player title
playerp = gr.Point(10, 70)
player_title = gr.Text(playerp, "Player")
player_title.draw(win)

#dealer title
dealerp = gr.Point(50, 70)
dealer_title = gr.Text(dealerp, "Dealer")
dealer_title.draw(win)

#buttons
hitp = gr.Point(30, 60)
hitButton = gr.Text(hitp, "Hit")
hitButton.draw(win)
hitbox = gr.Rectangle(gr.Point(25, 55), (gr.Point(35, 65)))
hitbox.draw(win)


standTextp = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 45), "Stand")
standTextp.draw(win)
standB = gr.Rectangle(gr.Point(25, 40), (gr.Point(35, 50)))
standB.draw(win)


newgp = gr.Point(30.5, 10)
newButton = gr.Text(newgp, "New Game")
newButton.draw(win)
newbox = gr.Rectangle(gr.Point(25.5, 5), (gr.Point(35.5, 15)))
newbox.draw(win)

#Hand Totals
handp = gr.Text(gr.Point(10, 10), "Player Hand Total:").draw(win)
dealt = gr.Text(gr.Point(50, 10), "Dealer Hand Total:").draw(win)

money_sign = gr.Text(gr.Point(27,70), "$").draw(win)
player_money = 100

money_point = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 70), player_money)
money_point.draw(win)

ls = []
for x in range(1, 20, 10):
    for y in range(20, 68, 8):
        p = gr.Point(x, y)
        p1 = gr.Point(x + 10, y + 8)
        rect = gr.Rectangle(p, p1)
        rect.draw(win)
        ls.append(rect)

dealer = []
for x in range(40, 60, 10):
    for y in range(20, 68, 8):
        p = gr.Point(x, y)
        p1 = gr.Point(x + 10, y + 8)
        rect = gr.Rectangle(p, p1)
        rect.draw(win)
        dealer.append(rect)

#player's text markers
playertext = []
for x in range(6, 20, 10):
    for y in range(23, 68, 8):
        p = gr.Point(x, y)
        playertext.append(p)

#dealer's text markers
dealertext = []
for x in range(45, 60, 10):
    for y in range(23, 68, 8):
        p = gr.Point(x, y)
        dealertext.append(p)

#assemble deck
def card_deck():
    # sets the card types and values
    card_value = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
    card_type = ['Hearts', 'Spades', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds']
    deck = []
    #This iterates all 52 cards into a deck
    for i in card_type:
        for j in card_value:
            deck.append(j + ' of ' + i)
    return deck

def card_value(card):
    #only reading first slice to determine value of the card
    if card[:1] in ('J', 'Q', 'K', '1'):
        return int(10)
    elif card[:1] in ('2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'):
        # card[:1] example '2' out of the full '2 of Hearts' string
        return int(card[:1])
    elif card[:1] == 'A':
            if total <= 10:
                return int(11)
            elif total >= 11:
                return int(1)

def player_draw():
    card1 = random.choice(card_deck())
    return card1

players_hand = []

#starting hand
start = player_draw()
valu1 = card_value(start)
starhand = gr.Text(playertext[0], start).draw(win).setSize(10)
start = player_draw()
valu2 = card_value(start)
start2 = gr.Text(playertext[1], start).draw(win).setSize(10)
total = valu1 + valu2
hand_total = gr.Text(gr.Point(10, 6), total)
hand_total.draw(win)

#dealer's starting hand
dstart = player_draw()
valu3 = card_value(dstart)
dstarthand1 = gr.Text(dealertext[0], dstart).draw(win).setSize(12)
dstart = player_draw()
valu4 = card_value(dstart)
dstarthand2 = gr.Text(dealertext[1], dstart).draw(win).setSize(12)
total2 = valu3 + valu4
dhand_total = gr.Text(gr.Point(50, 6), total2)
dhand_total.draw(win)


#defining the buttons
def buttons():
    hitp = gr.Point(30, 60)
    hitButton = gr.Text(hitp, "Hit")
    hitButton.draw(win)
    hitbox = gr.Rectangle(gr.Point(25, 55), (gr.Point(35, 65)))
    hitbox.draw(win)

    standTextp = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 45), "Stand")
    standTextp.draw(win)
    standB = gr.Rectangle(gr.Point(25, 40), (gr.Point(35, 50)))
    standB.draw(win)

    newgp = gr.Point(30.5, 10)
    newButton = gr.Text(newgp, "New Game")
    newButton.draw(win)
    newgme = gr.Rectangle(gr.Point(25.5, 5), (gr.Point(35.5, 15)))
    newgme.draw(win)

    return hitbox, standB, newgme

def inside(point, rectangle):
    ll = rectangle.getP1()
    ur = rectangle.getP2()

    return ll.getX() < point.getX() < ur.getX() and ll.getY() < point.getY() < ur.getY()


hit, stand, newgme = buttons()

s = win.getMouse()
handcount = 2
dealercount = 2
while True:
    clickPoint = win.getMouse()
    if clickPoint is None:
        print("")
    elif inside(clickPoint, hitbox):
        hand_total.undraw()
        playercard = player_draw()
        valu5 = card_value(playercard)
        point = gr.Text(playertext[handcount], playercard).draw(win).setSize(12)
        total = total + valu5
        hand_total = gr.Text(gr.Point(10, 6), total)
        hand_total.draw(win)
        handcount = handcount + 1
        if total > 21:
            pbust = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 20), "Player Busts")
            pbust.draw(win)
            money_point.undraw()
            player_money = player_money - 10
            money_point = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 70), player_money)
            money_point.draw(win)
            break
        if 25.5 <= s.getX() <= 35.5 and 5 <= s.getY() <= 15:
            continue
        elif total == 21:
            pwin = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 20), "Player Wins")
            pwin.draw(win)
            money_point.undraw()
            player_money = player_money + 10
            money_point = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 70), player_money)
            money_point.draw(win)
            break
        if 25.5 <= s.getX() <= 35.5 and 5 <= s.getY() <= 15:
            continue
    elif inside(clickPoint, standB):
        while total2 < 16:
            dhand_total.undraw()
            dealercard = player_draw()
            valu6 = card_value(dealercard)
            point = gr.Text(dealertext[dealercount], dealercard).draw(win).setSize(12)
            total2 = total2 + valu6
            dhand_total = gr.Text(gr.Point(50, 6), total2).draw(win)
            dealercount = dealercount + 1
            if total2 == 21 or 21 > total2 > total:
                p = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 20), "Dealer Wins")
                p.draw(win)
                money_point.undraw()
                player_money = player_money - 10
                money_point = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 70), player_money)
                money_point.draw(win)
                break
            if 25.5 <= s.getX() <= 35.5 and 5 <= s.getY() <= 15:
                continue
            elif total2 > 21:
                pwin = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 20), "Player Wins")
                pwin.draw(win)
                money_point.undraw()
                player_money = player_money + 10
                money_point = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 70), player_money)
                money_point.draw(win)
                break
            if 25.5 <= s.getX() <= 35.5 and 5 <= s.getY() <= 15:
                continue
            elif total2 == total:
                ppush = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 20), "Push")
                ppush.draw(win)
                break
            if 25.5 <= s.getX() <= 35.5 and 5 <= s.getY() <= 15:
                continue
        if 21> total > total2:
            pwin = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 20), "Player Wins")
            pwin.draw(win)
            money_point.undraw()
            player_money = player_money + 10
            money_point = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 70), player_money)
            money_point.draw(win)
            break
        if 25.5 <= s.getX() <= 35.5 and 5 <= s.getY() <= 15:
            continue
        if total2 == 21 or 21 > total2 > total:
            p = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 20), "Dealer Wins")
            p.draw(win)
            money_point.undraw()
            player_money = player_money - 10
            money_point = gr.Text(gr.Point(30, 70), player_money)
            money_point.draw(win)
            break
        if 25.5 <= s.getX() <= 35.5 and 5 <= s.getY() <= 15:
            continue

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

I want to get back to the first while loop (while True) when I click the "New Game" button so that I can start a new game but not lose the money gained or lost in the next round. How can I do that/what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which graphics library are you using? There is no stock `graphics` import and `pip install graphics` yields `No matching distribution found for graphics`

Comment: @jmkmay I am using a package from zelle...? here's the link for that: 
http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py